# this.getAttribute not working in web component while violating the spec

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element, native-web-component

I'm making a web component that will show "Hello {name}!" where `{name}` comes from `name="foo"`. When I try it I don't get any errors but it just displays "Hello null!".

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <hello-world name="Joe"></hello-world>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```js
class HelloWorld extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

    const p = document.createElement('p');

    p.innerHTML = `Hello ${this.getAttribute('name')}!`;

    this.shadowRoot.append(p);
  }
}

customElements.define('hello-world', HelloWorld);
```

In any situation lets assume that `name` will always have an input.

Comment: nvm fixed with `<script defer src="./script.js">`

Comment: That is a hack, your are making the JS execute **after** all DOM is parsed. Don't do DOM access in the ``constructor`` like connexo explains.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Strictly speaking, access its own attributes is not accessing the DOM; the reason not to do this is that in the dynamic creation case `new HelloWorld` or `document.createElement('hello-world')` the attribute won't be present. Relying on attributes in the constructor can easily make the element dysfunctional for those use-cases, even though in this specific case it won't even throw an error.

Comment: Is your question answered? If yes, please pick an answer. If no, please comment accordingly and explain what is missing or what doesn't fit your requirements.

Answer (score 5):

You must not read attributes in the `constructor`, otherwise you're violating the specification:

> [*The element's attributes and children must not be inspected, as in the non-upgrade case none will be present, and relying on upgrades makes the element less usable.*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance)
> From: `https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance`

You must delay this kind of work until the `connectedCallback` triggers, or, in the case of attributes, configure a proper `attributeChangedCallback`.

Conforming to the spec will also solve your initial issue, and it will greatly enhance the functionality and usefulness of your web component.

Please note that it's also not the smartest of ideas to pick an attribute name that already exists in the HTML specification, as a universal attribute.

```js
class HelloWorld extends HTMLElement {
  p = document.createElement('p');
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).append(this.p);
  }
  
  static get observedAttributes() { return ['greeting-name']; }
  attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldVal, newVal) {
    if (oldVal === newVal) return; // nothing to do
    switch (attr) {
      case 'greeting-name':
        this.p.textContent = `Hello ${newVal || 'world'}!`;
        break;
    }
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    if (!this.getAttribute('greeting-name')) { this.setAttribute('greeting-name', 'world'); }
  }
}

customElements.define('hello-world', HelloWorld);
```

```html
<hello-world greeting-name="Joe"></hello-world>

<hello-world id="foo"></hello-world>

<input type="text" oninput="document.getElementById('foo').setAttribute('greeting-name', this.value)" placeholder="Type a name" />
```

Comment: Do I need to use `document.createElement()` outside of the constructor or does it not matter?

Comment: @TacoSnack I move as much work as reasonably can be done into when I define the class properties, but that doesn' really matter too much.